# Using Fancybox 2 with Scriptculous?

Tags: fancybox

Has anyone successfully used both libraries together?  I can't seem to place the code in the properly sequence to get them to work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, you are doing this :

```
jQuery.noConflict(
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
   openEffect : 'none',
   closeEffect : 'none',
   helpers : {
    media : {}
   }
  });
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   openEffect : 'none',
   closeEffect : 'none'
  });
 }); 
);
```

... try this instead :

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
   openEffect : 'none',
   closeEffect : 'none',
   helpers : {
    media : {}
   }
  }); // first fancybox
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   openEffect : 'none',
   closeEffect : 'none'
  }); // second fancybox
}); // ready
```

Comment: I just tried your solution and fancybox still doesn't open up in the pop window unless i remove the jQuery.noConflict().

`code`
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
                openEffect: 'none',
                closeEffect: 'none',
                helpers: {
                    media: {}
                }
            });

            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                openEffect: 'none',
                closeEffect: 'none'
            });
        });

Comment: Ok I see the issue, I was missing "$" within the "function()".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jquery's noConflict() ? Since you are using two different libraries, it might be causing error. Using [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) function might help.

Comment: Yeah that wast initial trial but still can't get them to play nicely with each other.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that but still can't get them to play nice together.  

`code`jQuery.noConflict(
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
                    openEffect: 'none',
                    closeEffect: 'none',
                    helpers: {
                        media: {}
                    }
                });

                $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                    openEffect: 'none',
                    closeEffect: 'none'
                });
            });           
        );
`code`